# SQLAlchemy in Flask: do I need to close the database session?

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy

This is my first time writing a web application and using SQLAlchemy and I'm not sure I completely understand the concept of sessions. Currently I am loading a new session whenever the db needs to be queried. Is it sufficient to close it with sql_session.close() as I have done below?

Does not closing it cause many problems?

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db', echo=True)    
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class Kinases(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Kinase'

    full_name = Column(String)
    uniprot_code = Column(String)


def loadSession():
    metadata = Base.metadata
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return session


@app.route("/search/kinases/<query>")
def kinase_results(query):
    sql_session = loadSession()
    kinase = sql_session.query(Kinases).get(query)
    if kinase is None:
         return redirect(url_for('user_message', query=query))
    name = kinase.full_name
    sql_session.close()
```

Comment: Please consider using Flask-SQLAlchemy, since you're using Flask. It handles the session's lifetime for you.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, creating session in scope of view is a bad idea. Please read [session basics](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html) for sqla.

Comment: I suppose you mean "creating the `Session` class"?

Comment: No. I may be wrong, but session should be bind to broader context. Ideally – per request.

Comment: I'd say you're spot on.